# Is there a way to tell if a release is fired by a schedule in octopus

Tags: continuous-deployment, octopus-deploy

We have a project in Octopus that has been configured to release to an environment on a schedule.

In the process definition we use a step template for Slack to send the team a notification when a release takes place. We would like to avoid sending this Slack message if the release was fired by the schedule - rather than user initiated.

I was hoping there would be a system variable that we could check before running the Slack step - but I can't seem to find anything documented as such, and google didn't turn anything up.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Octopus 2019.5.0 or later, there are two variables that will be populated if the deployment was created by a trigger.

- Octopus.Deployment.Trigger.Id
- Octopus.Deployment.Trigger.Name

You can see the details at https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Issues/issues/5462

For your Slack step, you can use this run condition to skip it if the trigger ID is populated.

```
#{unless Octopus.Deployment.Trigger.Id}True#{/unless}
```

I hope that helps!